# Finding third-party libraries in CMake

Tags: build, cmake

I am trying to link to a 3rd party library.

I make/install the 3rd party library with:

```
svn co https://svn.company.nl/svn/eigen3/trunk eigen 
mkdir eigen/build
cd eigen/build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
mingw32-make -j3
mingw32-make install
```

The library is installed by default to

```
<CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX>/<INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR>
```

Using the following default values:

```
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX: C:/Program Files (x86)/Eigen3
INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR:  include/eigen3
```

Next, I have a number of projects where I want to use this library.  Fortunately, the library provides a FindEigen3.cmake file, so I should be able to do this in my cmake file:

```
set( CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
Find_Package(Eigen3)
```

If that worked, I wouldn't be here.  Find_Package does not find Eigen3.  FindEigen3.cmake contains:

```
find_path(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library
    HINTS
    ENV EIGEN3_ROOT 
    ENV EIGEN3_ROOT_DIR
    PATHS
    ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include
    ${KDE4_INCLUDE_DIR}
    PATH_SUFFIXES eigen3 eigen
  )
```

I've set:

```
set EIGEN3_ROOT="C:/Program Files (x86)/Eigen3"
set EIGEN3_ROOT_DIR="C:/Program Files (x86)/Eigen3/include/eigen3"
```

however, I still cannot find my library.  I've confirmed that 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Eigen3\include\eigen3\signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library` exists so I'm confused about why Find_Package() can't find my library.  In addition, I'd prefer to be able to do this without setting environment variables as I need to keep this simple for people using my library so that they can simply `cmake .. & make` and I'll take care of all dependencies for them.

I have no problems doing this in linux or cygwin.  It's the windows environment that's getting me.